# keystoreの使い回し

Tags: unity3d

Unityで２つ目のアプリを作ろうとしています。
keystoreの入力欄で，（Browse keystoreから）１つ目のアプリのxxx.keystoreを選択し，パスワードを入力したのですが，aliasでunsignedしか選択できません。

以下の情報ではkeystoreもaliasも１つでいいとあるのですが，どうすれば１つで開発することができますか？
[ここの情報](http://blog.aroundit.net/android-keystore-alias/)

（以下の画像は，Browse Keystore を押す前の画面です）
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。

AndroidSDKを外付けハードディスクに入れていたので，接続した状態であれば，既存のAliasが表示されました。